# What's wrong with my regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I want to check my fileName which can be `2013_09_北京.doc` or `2013_09_广东_1.doc` or `2013_09_中国人_anywords.doc`,but I find that `2013_09_北京.doc` is checked OK,but `2013_09_广东_1.doc` seems wrong,what's wrong with my codes?

```
 // fileName='2013_09_北京.doc'；// right
 fileName='2013_09_北京_1.doc'；// wrong
var patt1 = new RegExp("^2013_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])_([\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]{2,3})(_[\S]*)?\.(doc)$");
        if (!patt1.test(fileName)) {
         alert('input format like 2013_09_北京.doc或2013_09_北京_1.doc’);
        }
        else
        alert('right format!');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not escape \S and \. in your string, this should fix it:

```
var patt1 = new RegExp("^2013_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])_([\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]{2,3})(_[\\S]*)?\\.(doc)$");
```

Comment: Could you tell me why `.` should be writen by `\\.` instead of `\.`.Now I know that `\s` should be writen by `\\s` because `\s` has already be used.But in face `\.` has not be used.

Comment: Actually you don't have to escape \s because it 'has already been used', but because you have to escape every instance of \ to \\. Because of the same reason \. turns into \\.

Comment: Thank you,could you tell me why I can not use `@` in the js(MVC)?  `var patt1 = new RegExp("@^2013_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])_([\u4e00-\u9fa5]{2,3})(_[\S]*)?(\.doc)$");`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by putting the @ sign there?

Comment: Hi,In MVC js you should use `@@` to replace `@`.

Comment: Yes, but why whould you want an @ sign at that position in your regular expression?

Comment: @Borre,I use @ sign to unescape character,but after I try,@user2374716,I find the two codes are different result.  `var patt1 = new RegExp("@@^2013_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])_([\u4e00-\u9fa5]{2,3})(_[\S]*)?(\.doc)$");``var patt1 = new RegExp("^2013_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])_([\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]{2,3})(_[\\S]*)?(\\.doc)$");`

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't get what you are trying to say. As far as JavaScript goes, the regular expression I posted is fine. I understand you are using Razor to try to escape something, but it is unclear to me what that is.